# post order for binary search tree

Tags: binary-search-trees

I got this as the post order sequence but the answer says it is wrong. I do get a bit confused with the post order logic as well.

8 11 10 9 13 16 18 15

[image]

Comment: 13 should be the last node visited. The order is (left subtree), (right subtree), (root). You are not exploring 13's right subtree first.

Comment: I realised there are two 13's in the tree and I miseed one out in my sequence, so it would be 8 11 10 9 13 16 18 15 13?

Comment: Two nodes with the same key? If yes, then this is not classic BST

Comment: @Holz, yes. The sequence in your comment looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are two `13` in the Binary Search Tree.

The left node of 15 can not be a  13 since it violates the BST property.

Instead, it can be replaced with `14` or any value in `(13,15)`.

Resultant Traversal will be `8 11 10 9 x 16 18 15 13`

where x is the value you choose to replace the left child of `15`

Answer (score 0):

The correct ordering is $8, 11, 10, 9, 13,16,18,15,13$